# VB.NET: Manipulating TextBox Input: Dash every 5 characters and removing special characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

Essentially I am trying to replicate the Windows 7 (In-Windows) activation key TextBox form. The Form where it will auto capitalize letters, remove or deny all non alphanumeric characters except dashes every 5 characters that will be auto-input.

I assume this can be done with a fairly complicated replacement Regular Expression but I cannot seem to create one to fit the needs.

This is an Example of what I have right now, but it creates an infinite loop as it removes all characters including dashes, than adds a dash, which changes the text and removes the dash again.

Any suggestions, solutions or ideas would be appreciated!

**Code modified from original question to the solution I am using:**

```
      Private Sub aKeyTextField_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles aKeyTextField.KeyPress
    'Test only
    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim test As String = ""
        Select Case e.KeyChar
            Case "0" To "9"
                ' Do nothing
            Case "a" To "z"
                e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
            Case Else
                e.Handled = True
        End Select
    ElseIf Not e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(8) Then

        e.KeyChar = ""
        End If


        Dim strKeyTextField As String = aKeyTextField.Text
        Dim n As Integer = 5
    Dim intlength As Integer = aKeyTextField.TextLength

    If Not e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(8) Then

        While intlength > 4 And intlength < 29

            If aKeyTextField.Text.Length = 5 Then
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(5, "-")

            End If

            Dim singleChar As Char
            singleChar = strKeyTextField.Chars(n)

            While (n + 5) < intlength

                If singleChar = "-" Then
                    n = n + 6

                    If n = intlength Then
                        strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(n, "-")
                    End If
                End If

            End While

            intlength = intlength - 5
        End While
        aKeyTextField.Text = strKeyTextField

        'sets focus at the end of the string
        aKeyTextField.Select(aKeyTextField.Text.Length, 0)


    Else

        Select Case aKeyTextField.Text.Length
            Case 7
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Remove(5, 1)
            Case 13
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Remove(11, 1)
            Case 19
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Remove(17, 1)
            Case 25
                strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Remove(23, 1)
            Case Else



        End Select

        aKeyTextField.Text = strKeyTextField
        aKeyTextField.Select(aKeyTextField.Text.Length, 0)

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim blankContextMenu As New ContextMenu
    aKeyTextField.ContextMenu = blankContextMenu


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, it could prob do with tidying up and comments but I just wanted to see if I could get this working:

```
Private Sub aKeyTextField_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles aKeyTextField.KeyPress
    'Test only
    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        Dim test As String = ""
        Select Case e.KeyChar
            Case "0" To "9"
                ' Do nothing
            Case "a" To "z"
                e.KeyChar = Char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar)
            Case Else
                e.Handled = True
        End Select
    Else
        e.KeyChar = ""
    End If


    Dim strKeyTextField As String = aKeyTextField.Text
    Dim n As Integer = 5
    Dim intlength As Integer = aKeyTextField.TextLength
    While intlength > 4

        If aKeyTextField.Text.Length = 5 Then
            strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(5, "-")

        End If

        Dim singleChar As Char
        singleChar = strKeyTextField.Chars(n)

        While (n + 5) < intlength

            If singleChar = "-" Then
                n = n + 6

                If n = intlength Then
                    strKeyTextField = strKeyTextField.Insert(n, "-")
                End If
            End If

        End While

        intlength = intlength - 5
    End While
    aKeyTextField.Text = strKeyTextField

    'sets focus at the end of the string
    aKeyTextField.Select(aKeyTextField.Text.Length, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for staying with it Paul! I believe this will fit my needs, I will just need to add something in-case someone were to right-click and paste in the field rather than manually enter keys.

Comment: Please I could be of some help, I know the solution is far from perfect as you can't delete but I'm sure you can add another case to deal with this easily enough. The paste issue will def need another approach I would have thought, good luck

Comment: I ended up adding backspace capability and disablement of the context menu for paste. CTRL + V is already disabled due to the send key method blocking it. In the future I would like to rather edit the paste than deny it if possible but this fits the needs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx). You should be able to achieve your aims with little code and not need the regex.

Comment: I like this, the only issue is that it leaves ever-lasting -'s and _'s or spaces when no text is in that ruins the exact effect I wanted. Worse-to-worse I can use this as a back-up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of doing this on the `TextChangedEvent` of the `TextBox` to handle this in the `Set` method of the property that you are backing the textbox with.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have the ^ in the wrong place here, it needs to be inside the square brackets, also remove the {5}-, this will then remove all the non alphanumeric characters.

```
 If m.Success Then
            aKeyTextField.Text = Regex.Replace(aKeyTextField.Text, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+, "")"
            aKeyTextField.SelectionStart = aKeyTextField.TextLength
 End If
```

This code below will only put a - at the 5th position only and you need to add it to every 5 characters, create a loop / get the length and divide by 5 and add a "-" every 5 position.

```
If aKeyTextField.TextLength > 5 Then

        aKeyTextField.Text = aKeyTextField.Text.Insert(5, "-")
        aKeyTextField.SelectionStart = aKeyTextField.TextLength

  End If
```

Something like this would work instead:

```
Dim n As Integer = 5
        Dim intlength As Integer = aKeyTextField.Length
        While intlength > 0 And n < intlength
            aKeyTextField = aKeyTextField.Insert(n, "-")
            intlength = intlength - 5
            n = n + 6
        End While
```

To stop the infinite looping change the event to Validating instead:

```
Private Sub aKeyTextField_TextValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles aKeyTextField.Validating
```

Comment: I did not realize the Insert issue, so I am glad you pointed that out. The main reason I did not notice though is because I could never get that far. Running this code as is creates an infinite loop when I get to the 5th character. The issue with the RegEx removing special characters and adding the dashes is that it's creating an INFINITE LOOP and I need to get around this infinite loop. The whole {5} and messed up ^ was during my attempts to fix that, I just forgot to change it back.

Comment: I ran my code above in visual studio (not using a text box) but just passing in a string with some non alphanumeric characters and my code runs fine and removes all the characters and then loops through and puts a - every 5th character. I don't get an infinite loop at any point?

Comment: The issue is that it's running under ' textchanged ' so any time the textbox changes, including removing a special character or adding dashes it changes the text and runs itself again.

Comment: I see, can't you could add a flag so that it only runs the regex code one time only?

Comment: @Zachet, updated my answer using Validating event, tested and no infinite loop! Even is only fired once after you tab out of the textbox

Comment: While that does get around the issue, unfortunately I wanted to continue to have a live sense to it as it manipulates the string on the fly like the Windows 7 (In-Windows) activation key TextBox form. For example if you were right-click on 'My Computer' > 'Properties' > 'Scroll Down' > 'Change Product Key'/'Activate Product Key'.

Comment: Ok I guess it can't be done with text change event! I've just been looking at the keypress change event and believe I have it working. I'll post the answer below. See what you think